# Pandas: combined bar plot and line plot displays incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a bar plot of time-stamp precipitation data with a line plot of time-stamp flow data using pandas version 0.18.1. I am using the latest distribution of Anaconda, python 3.5.

If I plot them both as line plots, everything is displayed as normal. However, when I plot the precipitation data as a bar plot, I get very strange black lines drawn in the plot display outside of the plotting area.

Here is my code for plotting them on two sub-plots, with a shared x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')

pdf = pd.read_csv('precip.csv', delimiter=',', header=None, index_col=0)
pdf.columns = ['p']

qdf = pd.read_csv('manhole_B.csv', delimiter=',', header=None, index_col=0)
qdf.columns = ['q']

f, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
pdf.plot.bar(ax=ax[0])
qdf.plot(ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```

Here is the output i get, with strange black lines appearing around the plot:

[Strange plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBSZa.png)

I get a similar issue when plotting on the same subplot, with a secondary y axis. However, with both data frames plotted as line plots, everything displays correctly.

Can anyone help me with this? I could not find a post where someone had a similar issue occur.

EDIT: Here is what the data looked like. It ranges over two months, with the precipitation data sampled hourly and the flow data every 15 minutes, so if those are being all displayed as tick marks or labels, that would be where the lines are coming from.  After searching for the tick mark issue, I found plots that displayed similarly, so I am working out how to limit the number of tick marks and axis labels.

```
6/1/2016 0:00  56.8
6/1/2016 0:15  52.1
6/1/2016 0:30  44.0
6/1/2016 0:45  43.6
6/1/2016 1:00  34.3
```

EDIT: I have gotten the labels to display correctly, by adding this to my code in order to set tick labels to display once per week for hourly data.

```
n = 24*7
ticks = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
ticklabels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks[::n])
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels[::n])
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: Aren't the black lines tick marks (crunched together)?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without sample data, but those strange black lines could be the tick marks on the x-axis.  Try adding `rot=30` to your `plot` functions to rotate the text by 30 degrees.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I tried plotting just as a bar plot and had the same issue. I should have done that before - I was thinking the issue was specific to the combined bar and line plot.